# Rich Text Format: Overlapping cells

Tags: rtf, word-2010, word-2007

I have a little problem with RTF:
In our company, we are using a software, where you can send reports to a printer. The report is a RTF-file, created by the software, which uses a RTF-template to create the file, and then sends it to the default printer.

It will print just fine (everything is formatted correctly), but if you want to print a report, which has a table in it, **while** having a Word document open, the content from all the cells from one row will be shown in the first cell. It looks like, that it would write one text over the other. [Here's a Picture of what the table content looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnovP.jpg)

But this only happens the first time. When you print the same report again, all the cells are in their correct positions.

Word is set as the default application, to view RTF-files.

This problem only appears with the Office versions 2007 and 2010 in combination with Windows 7. With Office 2003 and Windows XP there is no such a problem. The software works properly. It seems like a problem, caused by Office (2007+).

Is there a known issue since Office 2007, regarding tables in RTF-files?

Greetings,
Spooky

Comment: yes, seems it is an issue with specific product version. btw, you can upload picture to image hosting server, such as imgur.com and provide a link to this picture in your post.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov - True story. Thank you for the hint. Didn't thought of a image hosting server.